# Keychain problem with Norton VPN

Tags: macos, keychain, vpn

I have an iMac with the latest version of Safari. Every time I try to connect Norton VPN, a box pops up on the screen as follows:

> NEIKEvProvider wants to sign using key Norton: in your keychain.

Under this is a password line.  I have no idea what this is about, and I certainly do not know the password.  While this message is on the screen, I cannot access the internet.  Can you help me?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the dialog? Most likely it is the access dialog for your keychain, so your login password should work.

Comment: It's probably just your the login password for your Mac which is requested to confirm that NEIKEvProvider is allowed access to your keychain.